# string to array return array in parameter

Tags: php, arrays, string, parameters

I get a string something like this, `"voornaam, achternaam"`
I give that to a function.

When I used the string to get the data from the database.

`mysql_query("SELECT."$string". FROM ...")`

this all goes good.

Now. I want to give back the values that I selected from the DB.

I tried something like this.

```
<?php
function user_info($user_id, $fetch = "")
{
if (ctype_digit($user_id))
{
    if (empty($fetch))
    {
        $fetch = "*";
    }
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ".$fetch." FROM accounts WHERE ID = '".$user_id."'");
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $data['password'] = NULL;
}

if (empty($fetch))
{
    return $data;
}
else
{
    $fetch = explode(", ", $fetch);
    print_r($fetch);
    while($param = $fetch) {
        return $data[$param];
    }
}

//$item_result['created_by'] gives back a digit
user_info($item_result['created_by'], 'voornaam, achternaam')
```

Im stuck in the while loop.
I am not realy that good in the loops.
So i tried something and to me its seems logical.
But in some way it wont work.

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code so we can see how an with which API and so on you fetch your data. Also where are you stuck?

Comment: From where you are getting `$param`?

Comment: But I still don't really see where you are stuck/ what isn't working as you want it to?

Comment: @sgtBOSE I think it fell from the sky :)

Comment: @Rizier123 It seems that Lenap is stuck with while loop

Comment: `$param` is from the `while` or did I do it turned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try change

```
  while($param = $fetch) {
    return $data[$param];
}
```

on foreach loop:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($featch as $key){
  $temp[$key] = (empty($data[$key]) ? ''  :  $data[$key] );
}
return $temp;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Or you can use for loop :

```
$temp = array();
for( $i =0; $i < count($fetch); $i++){
  $temp[$fetch[$i]] = (empty($data[$fetch[$i]]) ? ''  :  $data[$fetch[$i]] );
}
return $temp;
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

OR while loop

```
$temp = array();
while(count($fetch)){
  $key = array_shift($fetch);
  $temp[$key] = (empty($data[$key]) ? ''  :  $data[$key] );
}
return $temp;
```

Comment: My boss wont use foreach. If it was to me to decide I already used foreach

Comment: @Lenap sorry, but I didn't understand what you wanted to tell. There are a lot of possibilities to make loop.

Comment: Im tryng one of these things;)

Comment: Used the foreach loop.

Comment: Well.. I used first a forloop and then foreach

Answer (score 2):

It is working now!

What I have now is:

```
$fetch = explode(", ", $fetch);
    $temp = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fetch); $i++) {
        $temp[$fetch[$i]] = (empty($data[$fetch[$i]]) ? '' : $data[$fetch[$i]]);
    }
    foreach ($temp as $data) {
        echo $data . ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is in -

```
$fetch = explode(", ", $fetch);
print_r($fetch);
while($param = $fetch) {
    return $data[$param];
}
```

> `$fetch` is an array now and `$param` is not defined.

You can try this -

```
$fetch = explode(", ", $fetch);
$i = 0;
$newData = array();
while($i < count($fetch)) {
    $newData[$fetch] = $data[$fetch];
    $i++;
}
return $newData;
```

I would suggest to use `foreach` instead of `while`.

Comment: return $data[$fetch]; - will return only one value not all of them from $fetch array

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the following if it HAS to be in a while loop

```
$data=array();
while (list($var, $val) = each($fetch)) {
        $data[$var]=$val;
}
```

Comment: From code in question = $data - is array from mysql, and $fetch is keys what should be reutrn. so this is not quiet correct code

Comment: Its an example of the another way of doing it. SO isnt a code writing service, you can read and adapt the solution to your own code.